# How to Insert Records based on the Previous Insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert

Here's my procedure:

```
PROCEDURE add_values
AS
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO TABLE_A ...
   SELECT t.id, t.name FROM TABLE_C ("This selection will return multiple records")

END
```

While it inserts in TableA, I would like insert into another table(TableB) for that particular record which got inserted in tableA.

The columns in TableA and TableB are different. Is it wise to call a function before inserting into TableB - I would like to perform certain gets and sets based on the id inserted in tableA?

Comment: @Michael: Why, when you can run multiple SQL statements in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Inputs**

```
declare @tblA table (id int,name varchar(20))
declare @tblB table (id int,name varchar(20))
declare @tblC table (id int identity,name varchar(20))
insert into @tblC 
    select 'name1' union all select 'name2' union all
    select 'name3' union all select 'name4' union all
    select 'name5' union all select 'name6' union all
    select 'name7' union all select 'name8' union all
    select 'name9' union all select 'name10' union all
    select 'name11' union all select 'name12' union all
    select 'name13' union all select 'name14' union all
    select 'name15' union all select 'name16' union all
    select 'name17' union all select 'name18' union all
    select 'name19' union all select 'name20'
```

**Query**

```
insert @tblA 
output INSERTED.id, INSERTED.Name
into @tblB 
select 
    id,name
from @tblC 
where id % 2 = 0

select * from @tblA
select * from @tblB
```

**Output:** [ For both table A & B]

id  name

```
2   name2
4   name4
6   name6
8   name8
10  name10
12  name12
14  name14
16  name16
18  name18
20  name20
```

Basically I am inserting those records into TableA from TableC whose id's are even. And then by using Output clause inserting the values from  TableA to TableB

For more information [OUTPUT Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Hope this makes sense

Comment: While it inserts in TableA i would like insert into another table(TableB) for that particular record which got inserted in tableA Note:The columns in TableA and TableB are different , is it wise to call a function before inserting into TableB as i would like to perform certain gets and sets based on the id inserted in tableA.

I would like to do in one go,insert in tableA perform sets based on the id inserted in TableA and then insert into tableB

Comment: Perform the insertion into table A. Use a function to perform the operations for table B. Then use either MERGE or TABLE VALUED PARAMETER to accomplish the task. Hope this answers

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL try `INSERT..SELECT`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA where id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: That's for MySQL - the question is tagged for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger to do it, if this is the only way you insert data into the table.
(otherwise it will run on every insert)

or you can iterate on a cursor which will enable you to do it with every insert from the selection

([Cursor example](http://www.jackdonnell.com/articles/SQL_CURSOR.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The best technique depends on the details of your table definitions and the associated queries.  Based on the info in your question, maybe something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_values
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANS
    INSERT INTO TableA
      SELECT id, name FROM TableC
    INSERT INTO TableB
      SELECT id, name FROM TableC
  COMMIT
END
```

Comment: While it inserts in TableA i would like insert into another table(TableB)
for that particular record which got inserted in tableA
Note:The columns in TableA and TableB are different , is it wise to call a function before inserting into TableB as i would like to perform certain gets and sets based on the id inserted in tableA.

Comment: My answer above will insert exactly the same records into TableB that were inserted into TableA.  It's difficult to provide more meaningful advice without more concrete requirements. It would help if you could update your question with specific table definitions, what you mean by "certain gets and sets," etc.