# Is it wiser to use a function in between First and Next Insertions based on Select?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
 PROCEDURE add_values 
 AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA 
       SELECT id, name 
       FROM TableC ("This selection will return multiple records")
```

While it inserts in TableA i would like insert into another table(TableB) for that particular record which got inserted in tableA

Note:The columns in TableA and TableB are different , is it wise to call a function before inserting into TableB as i would like to perform certain gets and sets based on the id inserted in tableA.

Comment: You have already asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814897/how-to-insert-records-based-on-the-previous-insert/1815035#1815035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert a set of rows into two tables, you'd have to store it in a temporary table first and then do the two INSERT statement from there

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
   SELECT id, name 
   FROM TableC ("This selection will return multiple records")

INSERT INTO TableA
   SELECT (fieldlist) FROM #TempTable

INSERT INTO TableB
   SELECT (fieldlist) FROM #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Marc_S answer, one more way is

First insert the needed records into Table A from Table C. Then pump the needed records from Table A to Table B

Though many ways has been suggested by many peoples in your question that u asked just 3 hrs ago [How to Insert Records based on the Previous Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814897/how-to-insert-records-based-on-the-previous-insert/1815035#1815035)